# Open office writter unsaved warning are gone in newer version

Tags: libreoffice

I'm on ubuntu 20.04, switching from 16.04 and I noticed that libre office writer don't warn me anymore when a document is unsaved. Before there where an icon or *** showing beside the name of the project when unsaved.

It was a little warning that I appreciated a lot in my work dealing with hundred of sheets. Is there a way to configure it again or could I install an old version? I'm planning to use mint one day, can it changes something for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ah it's funny, I noticed that there is actually a warning , the save icon is an arrow, blue for save, red for unsaved. It is a very small detail, I liked it better with the * beside the title.

Comment: [Lots of people agree with you](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/65018/why-did-you-change-the-save-button-2016-edition/), too 